# Show that T is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Let B be an element of $R^{n \times n}$ and define $T(A) = BAB$ for all $A \in R^{n \times n}$. Show that T is a linear transformation.

I am completely lost and I do not know how to start this.

Answer (score 1):

Here $ T(aA)=BaAB=aBAB=aT (A)$ $\forall a\in \mathbb { R } $

And $T(A+C)=B(A+C)B=BAB+BCB=T(A)+T(C)$ $\forall A,C\in \mathbb {R}^{n\times n}$

Thus $T$ is linear.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy if one works from the axiomatic definition of linearity.  Recall that $T$ is a linear transformation if and only if

$T(\alpha X + \beta Y) = \alpha T(X) + \beta T(Y), \tag{1}$

for all $\alpha, \beta \in R$ and all $X, Y \in R^{n \times n}$.  So we have

$T(\alpha X + \beta Y) = B(\alpha X + \beta Y)B = B(\alpha X)B + B(\beta Y)B = \alpha BXB + \beta BYB = \alpha T(X) + \beta T(Y); \tag{2}$

$T$ is thus a linear transformation operating on $R^{n \times n}$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: What is fiat lux?

Comment: @ellya:  Latin for "Let there be light!"  Motto of Harvard University, as well as having other cultural significance.

Comment: @1950RobertLewis Isn't the motto of Harvard University "Veritas"?  Wikipedia suggests you might be thinking of the UC system.

Comment: @ErickWong:  you might be right but *Fiat Lux* appears on their shield, so I assumed; or perhaps I should say its *a* motto etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @1950RobertLewis Ummm, mind sharing a link to the shield? :)

Comment: @ErickWong:  guess what, you're right and I'm wrong on this one!  It is the motto, however, of the University of California, from which I hold two post-baccalaureate degrees, and is on Sather Gate at Cal Berkeley, about a block from where I write this post!  here's a link:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_California.  All I can say is:  d'ohhh!